# Seeing logs of dask workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm having trouble changing the temporary directory in Dask. When I change the temporary-directory in dask.yaml for some reason Dask is still writing out in /tmp (which is full). I now want to try and debug this, but when I use `client.get_worker_logs()` I only get INFO output.

I start my cluster with

```
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client

cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=4, memory_limit='10gb')

client = Client(cluster)
```

I already tried adding `distributed.worker: debug` to the `distributed.yaml`, but this doesn't change the output. I also check I am actually changing the configuration by calling `dask.config.get('distributed.logging')`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default LocalCluster silences most logging.  Try passing the `silence_logs=False` keyword

```
cluster = LocalCluster(..., silence_logs=False)
```